# Split a dataset in training and test in one line in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

That's not a very important point, I know, but I would like to know if I can save two lines of code.

I have a dataset inputData that I want to split in two parts. I'm using the method randomSplit of the dataset class. However, I am forced to use three lines of code for doing this:

```
    val sets = inputData.randomSplit(Array[Double](0.7, 0.3), 18)
    val training = sets(0)
    val test = sets(1)
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like

```
    val (training, test) = inputData.randomSplit(Array[Double](0.7, 0.3), 18)
```

but this code does not compile due to an Error:

```
Error:(146, 13) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2)
required: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]]
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: `randomSplit` returns an array, your variable is a tuple - indeed that's not the same and needs some conversion.

Comment: you can do `val (training, test) = (sets(0), sets(1))` to reduce to two lines. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern match the array:

```
val Array(training, test) = inputData.randomSplit(Array[Double](0.7, 0.3), 18)
```

or a longer (but still single expression)

```
val (training, test) = inputData.randomSplit(Array[Double](0.7, 0.3), 18) match {
   case Array(training, test) => (training, test)   
}
```

Please remember this it cannot be validated by the compiler and can fail on runtime with `MatchError`.